# “rails generate controller” is not creating a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I am following the Rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and when I ran this command: rails generate controller Welcome index I couldn't find the generated files. So I ran the rails server and noticed that it says it's loading the new generated files in /Users/joseph/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb

Weird? What's going on?

```
~/RubymineProjects/blog
% rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.5.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Amateur Raccoon Rocketry
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-07-19 20:38:04 -0700
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"internal"=>true}
  Rendering /Users/joseph/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/joseph/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (5.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 11.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Did you check app/controllers folder?

Comment: @gates yes, I checked and its not there. I am here: /Users/joseph/RubymineProjects/blog but it looks like it was generated here: /Users/joseph/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb

Comment: which ruby returns: /Users/joseph/.rbenv/shims/ruby and rails: aliased to _rails_command which bundle /Users/joseph/.rbenv/shims/bundle but if I'm running rails in a directory why is it pointing and building elsewhere?